# How to find out whether a dissolved company has been traded in stock markets?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ameriquest_Mortgage

I see the above company dissolved some years ago. I don't know whether its stock was traded in the stock market or not. How can I find this information? If it was traded, what was the ticker symbol?

Comment: what is the goal? do you want the symbol? or do you want to be able to find  the price on a specific day in the past?

Comment: I want the old stock ticker.

Comment: This press release indicates that at least as of 2006 it was a privately held company.  https://web.archive.org/web/20060922204734/http://www.atg.wa.gov/releases/2006/rel_Ameriquest_012306.html  It's possible that it was public earlier or went public between then and its collapse.  But I'd echo @mhoran_psprep and ask what you intend to do with this knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia names Citigroup as the successor organization. You should [reach out to them](https://www.citigroup.com/global/investors/investor-contacts).